# How to reference and update a file on S3 from Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I have a Rails 4 application that needs to use a number of excel files, representing rosters, (20 or so, grouped by their own individual committee) that have to be read in and editable by the User. Pre-deploy I had the system working perfectly where these files would live in `public/rosters` and could be referenced and edited by any authenticated user, unfortunately when I deployed to Heroku I could no longer do this.

I have been using an S3 bucket to host the other files necessary for this and other related apps, and it's been working wonderfully, for what I've been using it for; so I decided to try it as a solution to this problem. Unfortunately it would appear as if I could only access the files the way I had been by making them publicly accessible, which is not something that I want to do.

So my question is this: what would be the best way to reference these files (using my `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` to authenticate ideally) and allow a User to push changes that will overwrite the file on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) to write file to S3 which works using `access_key_id`  and `secret_access_key`. Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html) documentation. Hope this helps. Thanks!